# How to initialize the C runtime when using a Windows executable as a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, testing, dll

I'm trying to do unit/component testing of classes and functions in my Windows executable. I want to run the actual compiled code without building the test cases into the executable*. The Microsoft tools are perfectly happy to export classes and functions from the executable and I can link to it as if it's a DLL. The catch - since the entry point of the dynamically loaded executable isn't being called and there's no DllMain (it's not technically a DLL), the C runtime isn't being initialized in the "DLL" and statics aren't being initialized**.

Is there a way to call CRT_INIT in the context of the dynamically loaded .EXE and get everything working or is this ridiculous?

*If I'm missing something blatantly obvious here feel free to point me in the right direction.

**This appears to be my biggest problem.

Comment: Just because there isn't a DLLMain in code, doesn't mean there isn't a DLLMain.  Since VS2003, there has been a default DLLMain provided if you don't have one.  Check using depends - you might find that there is a default DLLMain.  In that case you can use LoadLibrary and GetAddress for your testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer - I stand by my original answer.  **This is not supposed to work.** Best practice is to compile core code as a LIB or DLL and then to link this library into both the UnitTest code and the main program code.

But since the OP demonstrated to me that he did find a way to make an EXE work as a DLL, I feel compelled to bring him the rest of the way...

The trick is to call _CRT_INIT.  But since there is no DllMain invoked to obtain the HINSTANCE handle, you have to called GetModuleHandle directly to get it.  And then I keep a table to keep track of which threads have had CRT_INIT invoked for it.

I took the sample code he provided and added this data structure inside AppToTest.exe code:

```
bool g_isProcessInitialized = false;
std::map<DWORD, bool>* g_threadmap;

extern "C" BOOL __stdcall _CRT_INIT(HINSTANCE, DWORD, void*);

void ThreadInit()
{
    std::map<DWORD, bool>& themap = *g_threadmap;

    DWORD dwCurrentThreadID = ::GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread());
    if (themap[dwCurrentThreadID] == false)
    {
        _CRT_INIT(GetModuleHandle("AppToTest.exe"), DLL_THREAD_ATTACH, NULL);
        themap[dwCurrentThreadID] = true;
    }
}

void ProcessInit()
{
    if (g_isProcessInitialized == false)
    {
        _CRT_INIT(GetModuleHandle("AppToTest.exe"), DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL);
        _CRT_INIT(GetModuleHandle("AppToTest.exe"), DLL_THREAD_ATTACH, NULL);

        g_isProcessInitialized = true;

        g_threadmap = new std::map<DWORD, bool>();
        std::map<DWORD, bool>& themap = *g_threadmap;
        themap[GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread())] = true;
    }
}

void APPAPI InitializeCRT()
{
    ProcessInit();
    ThreadInit();
}
```

And then in TestApp.exe, I modified "main" to call InitializeCRT early:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitializeCRT();
```

And that seems to work - even after I uncommented out the call to the methods marked problematic.  If subsequent threads are created, then InitializeCRT might need to be called by those threads.  (It might work anyway...)

I can't believe this actually works.  Might not work on older versions of Windows. Shouldn't be done this way...

Comment: Indexing a map by thread ID probably isn't the best idea in the world ;) If two threads simultaneously index an entry that does not exist, they'll both modify the map's internal structure believing nothing else is doing so at the same time.Rare for sure, but TLS tends to work better for that kind of thing and avoids any locking that would be required to make the map thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work.  You can not dynamically load an EXE as if it was a DLL. There are some limited scenarios involving loading of resources from an EXE, but there's no exporting of functions.

You are better off compiling everything but WinMain as a LIB or DLL.  Then link both your UnitTest.EXE and YourProgram.EXE (each providing an implementation of main or WinMain) to this library.

Comment: Except that it _does_ work (mostly). I have the classes/functions I want exported already and am linking to them at build time and dynamically linking to them at run time. Classes/methods/functions which do **not** depend on static initialization work just fine. It's only those which do that are problematic.

Comment: @user3422499 - I suspect you are actually statically linking with the same code in both projects.  Feel free to post a minimal working example of a Visual Studio solution demonstrating one EXE dynamically linking to code from another EXE. I'm always willing to be educated. However, I'm fairly certain you can't do what you are describing.

Comment: In any case - my original answer still stands. That's typically how most Windows developers separate out their unit test code from their product code. On one product I worked on, we did include the unit tests in the EXE, but it was a separate build project (e.g. Debug, Release, and DebugUnitTest). Only the latter actually included the UT code.

Comment: A) I forgot to set the dependencies in the solution file, so you may need to manually build the AppToTest before building the TestHarness and B) once built, you can rename/remove the AppToTest.exe and verify that the TestHarness is actually loading it as a DLL and does not have its own copy of the class it is using.

Comment: @user3422499 - Wow.  It does work.  (I still don't like it). But in any case, I did figure out how to make it work and to call _CRT_INIT...  Answer coming shortly.